# How can I create new sheets for all filtered values in column T in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to take the unique values of T column, filter data of this column based on those filters, create a new sheet for each of those filters and then paste filtered data in this new sheet.

The code shown here results in an error "propertyget didn't work"
How can I do it?

```
Sub filtrer_copier_creeronglet()

Dim Rng As Range, List As Object
Dim i As Integer, lastrow As Long
Dim destsheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

' Référence à la feuille de données
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("donnees")

' Créer un objet dictionnaire pour stocker les valeurs uniques
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Compter les valeurs uniques dans la colonne T
For Each Rng In ws.Range("T2:T" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 20).End(xlUp).Row)
    If Not List.Exists(Rng.Value) Then List.Add Rng.Value, Nothing
Next Rng

' Boucle à travers les valeurs uniques
For i = 0 To List.count - 1
    ' Filtrer les données sur la colonne T avec la valeur unique
    ws.Range("A1:T" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 20).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=List.Keys(i)
    
    ' Copier les données filtrées (sauf les en-têtes) vers une nouvelle feuille
    Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count))
    destsheet.Name = List.Keys(i)
    ws.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destsheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Supprimer le filtre
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The error says "didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `List.Keys(0)` unless you assign to an intermediate array ie `ar = List.Keys` then use `For i = 0 to Ubound(ar)` and `Criteria1:=ar(i)`. Easier to just use `For Each k in List.Keys`.

```vb
    Dim k as Variant
    For Each k In List.keys
        ' Filtrer les données sur la colonne T avec la valeur unique
        ws.Range("A1:T" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=k
        
        ' Copier les données filtrées (sauf les en-têtes) vers une nouvelle feuille
        Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        destsheet.Name = k
        ws.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destsheet.Range("A1")
        
        ' Supprimer le filtre
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next k
```